# Hiding Options inside UI Grid Export menu

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-grid, export-to-pdf

I am using the UI grid export functionality to export all grid data in pdf/csv format. The problem is there is a "Columns" header as 1 of the options. How can I remove this columns option from menu?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found a solution: setting the following property of grid to false will hide the  "Columns" option from grid menu.

```
gridMenuShowHideColumns: false,
```